# WebAPI 2 and post parameters in body passed as null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi2 controller method as below:

```
[Route("shipment/{shipmentId:long}/quotes/register")]
public HttpResponseMessage ProvideQuote(long shipmentId, [FromBody]RegisterQuote quote)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, String.Format("quote of price {0} for shipment {1} has been registred", quote.QuotePrice, shipmentId));
    return response;
}
```

now the issue is that when I test the method using my REST client, the `quote` is always null.

here is how I am testing
[image]

parameter
[image]

now  the response I get is:
[image]

as you can see that the query string parameter is being passed correctly, but the body parameter is not passed. any idea what am I doing wrong.

**Edit 1:**

Request Header:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Authorization: Bearer Hhz54k1BLyPMJxucSeq4pLwhS3Y4Ez5WCoEMzhe-uH7gHMFMRjHE2Im9juinMLhqaHVZmkVrWetEiCsYbaduzLas7rYf-D3p40lH_q3IDEn2rdt122qpiHvnUr7Cz2b6GXiPYLGDMQFOMN0lbkYmoZe95sxXDRvDfpdJw4G2Fk3Ri1A25F3qAZCnBhjA-BLoL-2eAjxX-RPCGAXjaNLjT4zsxRJH8NP5qC7azPrWCDKRuK282hnTbKViQjMBDflwlxdPhTNkiCBtxWn03xRcxH9GD1z5Ca0Qinn5gUS7qWwCt9zoZtHcbwFY1kvxyx7x5yCuyEfrGHgKG1s7zjTPjNwU0eV7cC6xQA2GsOAnqADxMDyRryCRKLY7WcyQftRhZ70WbtSW2PI0F7qmDr8n0wvktmKglusLEDf4ib925n-ajVTyMl7v9O-9OsdgCj_GSNE6_bszd3Ak1yUurs-VoQ
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,kn;q=0.6
```

BTW I am not sure what happened to all my images though!

Regards
Kiran

Comment: Can you share how your request headers look like?

Comment: @KiranChalla: I have updated the request header

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are sending Json content in the body but have the content-type header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`...change the content-type header to `application/json` or `text/json` if want to send data in json...